# Объясните как работает деструктуризация в данном случаи?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Не могу понять как работает деструктуризация в данном примере.
В функцию `map` передается `callback` функция которая принимает в качестве аргументов три параметра, но в данном примере в аргументах деструктурируются две переменные, хотя никакого объекта не передается. Как это работает?

```js
buttons = [
    {one: 'asd', two: 'some'},
    {one: 'asd', two: 'some'},
    {one: 'asd', two: 'some'}
]

buttons.map(({one, two}) => {
    return console.log(`${one} ${two}`)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

В справке к методу [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) указано, что в передаваемый callback будет передано три значения:

```
 callback(currentValue, index, array)
```

Где `currentValue` — текущий обрабатываемый элемент массива.

В примере деструктурируется первый параметр, который и есть элемент массива, а все элементы массива buttons имеют свойства `one` и `two`